# Why was Cauchy studying Schur polynomials and related topics?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians

Let $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n$ be nonnegative integers. The Schur polynomial $s_{\lambda}(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ can be defined as the ratio
$$s_{\lambda}(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \frac{\det\left(x_i^{\lambda_j+n-j} \right)}{\Delta(x)} \qquad (\clubsuit)$$
where
$$\Delta(x) = \det \left( x_i^{n-j} \right) = \prod_{i<j} (x_i - x_j)$$
is the Vandermonde determinant. According to the historical notes in Stanley, *Enumerative Combinatorics*, Volume 2, Chapter 7, this ratio was first studied by Cauchy.

Nowadays, we know that Schur polynomials are important in the representation theory of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $S_n$, and in Schubert calculus. But Schur's thesis, where he related Schur polynomials to representation theory, is from 1918, and Schubert developed Schubert calculus in the 1870's. Cauchy is much earlier; he introduced these ratios in 1815 ([Mémoire sur les fonctions qui ne peuvent obtenir que deux valeurs égales et de signes contraires par suite des transpositions opérées entre les variables qu'elles renferment](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/oeitem?id=OE_CAUCHY_2_1_91_0)). So my first question is

> Why was Cauchy studying the ratio $(\clubsuit)$?

Continuing in this vein, the following formula is now known as Cauchy's identity:
$$\prod_{i,j=1}^n \frac{1}{1-x_i y_j} = \sum_{\lambda} s_{\lambda}(x) s_{\lambda}(y). \qquad (\diamondsuit)$$
Stanley writes that he can not find a source where Cauchy records $(\diamondsuit)$, but that $(\diamondsuit)$ can be deduced from Cauchy's determinantal identity:
$$\det \left( \frac{1}{u_i+v_j} \right) = \frac{\Delta(u) \Delta(v)}{\prod_{i,j} (u_i + v_j)} \quad (\heartsuit)$$
using the substitution $(u_i = -1/x_i, v_j = y_j)$ and the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula). (I understand how the deduction works; you don't need to explain this part.)

The identity $(\heartsuit)$ is due to Cauchy; it appears as an exercise in an 1841 paper ([Mémoire sur les fonctions alternées et sur les sommes alternées](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/oeuvres-completes/memoire-sur-les-fonctions-alternees-et-sur-les-sommes-alternees/31524DAEF99769C7EC05D6845E3B9B76)).  So my questions continue:

> Why was Cauchy studying $(\heartsuit)$? Did he know that $(\heartsuit)$ and $(\clubsuit)$ were related?

Note: I have linked Cauchy's papers above, and skimmed enough to make sure they are the right ones, but I haven't actually read them.

Comment: I would have added tags [symmetric-polynomials] and [determinants], but I don't have enough rep here to create them. Other tag suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: What did Cauchy himself say about it in the paper you linked? Just looking at the first page, he was interested in symmetric functions, which were studied since [Newton and Lagrange](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3654883). Lagrange related them to what later became Galois theory.